# Sending pictures with yagmail doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, yagmail

I'm trying to send png with yagmail module but i get this error :

[image]

Here is the code :

```
import yagmail
import os

currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
path_fichier_screenshot2 = currentDirectory + "\\screenshot2.png"
print(path_fichier_screenshot2)

try:
    yag = yagmail.SMTP(user="myemail", password='pwd')
    contents = [yagmail.inline(path_fichier_screenshot2)]
    yag.send("target_email", "test", contents)
    print("Email sent successfully")
except:
    print("Error, email was not sent")
```

When i just send text, it works.
Any clue ?

Comment: Do you want to send `png` as an attachment?

Comment: Hello, yes attachment or better, png included in email content. It just works with few words, when the content is too sizable, I can't send the email

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the image as an attachment, you can do this:

```
yag = yagmail.SMTP(user="myemail", password='pwd')
contents = "Hello , sending png as an attachment"
attachments = [path_fichier_screenshot2]

yag.send("target_email", "test", contents, attachments=attachments)
```

Refer to this [`doc`](https://blog.mailtrap.io/yagmail-tutorial/) for more information.

Comment: Hello, i think i've already done that and i had the same error. I will try again. Thanks for anwser